# Print NDVI Image File Size in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

With this code:

```
var ndvi = l8
    .filterDate('2018-06-01', '2018-08-01')
    .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER', 'less_than', 3)
    .map(ndvi)
    .select(ndvi)
    .mosaic().clip(roi);
```

how can I print NDVI file size???

for example I want to print "50 MB"

Answer (score 3):

Something like the below should work. It figures out the data type of each bands, how many bits used per pixel. Note that it doesn't take file compression into account (and maybe the pyramiding of assets is included in file size?), and will have some minor error due to partial pixels. But it should be good enough to give you an idea of the size.

```
function toImageSizeBytes(image, scale) {
  var imageDescription = ee.Dictionary(
    ee.Algorithms.Describe(image)
  )
  var bands = ee.List(
    imageDescription.get('bands')
  )
  var bits = ee.Number(bands.map(getBits).reduce(ee.Reducer.sum()))
  var pixelCount = image.geometry().bounds().area(scale)
    .divide(ee.Number(scale).pow(2))
    .sqrt()
    .ceil()
    .pow(2)
  return bits.divide(8).multiply(pixelCount).ceil()

  function getBits(band) {
    var dataType = ee.Dictionary(
      ee.Dictionary(band).get('data_type')
    )
    var precision = dataType.getString('precision')
    return ee.Algorithms.If(precision.equals('int'), 
      intBits(dataType),
      ee.Algorithms.If(precision.equals('float'),
        32,
        64
      )
    )
  }
  
  function intBits(dataType) {
    var min = dataType.getNumber('min')
    var max = dataType.getNumber('max')
    var types = ee.FeatureCollection([
      ee.Feature(null, {bits: 8, min: -Math.pow(2, 7), max: Math.pow(2, 7)}),
      ee.Feature(null, {bits: 8, min: 0, max: Math.pow(2, 8)}),
      ee.Feature(null, {bits: 16, min: -Math.pow(2, 5), max: Math.pow(2, 15)}),
      ee.Feature(null, {bits: 16, min: 0, max: Math.pow(2, 16)}),
      ee.Feature(null, {bits: 32, min: -Math.pow(2, 31), max: Math.pow(2, 31)}),
      ee.Feature(null, {bits: 32, min: 0, max: Math.pow(2, 32)})
    ])
    return types
      .filter(ee.Filter.lte('min', min))
      .filter(ee.Filter.gt('max', max))
      .merge(ee.FeatureCollection([ee.Feature(null, {bits: 64})]))
      .first()
      .getNumber('bits')
  }
}
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/e3804aff012a006e33b55b4cb1952c57

Comment: What an amazing answer! I could never resolve it out this good haha

Comment: Thanks! It's functionality I want to add to the system I'm working on, so I figured I could spend the time to implement it already now.